# Problema con recuperación de datos en CRUD PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, crud

Tengo una conexión con mi bbdd llamada conexión_2.php con este contenido:

```
<?php
/*Datos de conexion a la base de datos*/
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "root";
$db_name = "MCC_02_2018";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'No se pudo conectar a la base de datos : '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

La tabla que me interesa de mi bbdd es esta:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `p_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
    `nombre` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
    `titulo` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
    `entradilla` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
    `articulo` varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
    `fecha` date NOT NULL,
    `year` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `posts` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`);
```

Para recuperar los datos y que estos se lean en determinado lugar, tengo este código:

```
$mostrar_post = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM posts ORDER BY p_id DESC";
$result = $conexion->query($mostrar_post);
if($result){
    if($result->mysqli_num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "$row[titulo]";
        }
    }else {
        echo ("No hay datos");
    }
}else{
    echo("Error en la base de datos");
}
```

Y lo que sucede es que me da el mensaje:

> Error en la base de datos.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar, por favor?

Muchas gracias

Comment: tu contrasena de la base de datos en verdad es root?  `$db_pass = "root"; `

Comment: Bueno, ahí estoy trabajando en local, y en local uso esa contraseña. En el servidor remoto es otra, claro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por alguna extraña razón no está respetando el TOP 1, debe de ser así la consulta?
Por que no cambias por `$mostrar_post = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY p_id DESC LIMIT 1";`

Quizá pueda darte menos problemas

Comment: Puse el  "TOP 1" en el SELECT porque quiero obtener el id (p_id) más alto y, por tanto, más reciente. 
He puesto tu código en el SELECT y me da varios errores:

Comment: No, no da errores, ¡Muchas gracias!. Con tu código funciona